# WCF service and IIS IP restrictions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS running alongside a website. It makes some API calls into a third party CMS platform the site uses.

It's using userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" and has its own authentication. There's no impersonation or anything.

This service had no problems with API calls in the prior version of the CMS.

After upgrading, the third party has put IIS IP restrictions on some of its own local web services that its API uses.

The problem I'm having now is clients can connect to my WCF service, authentication works fine, but the API calls into those other services are failing.

I tried running the client on the web server as a test and the API calls worked (localhost is allowed in the restrictions). Outside the web server, the calls in the service fail. This seems to be due to the IP restrictions.

I need all calls from that WCF service to be allowed once the client is authenticated, regardless of the client calling it.

Is there a configuration or something I can do to get that to work with the restrictions check?

Comment: First you need to figure out HOW they are doing IP restrictions.. there are probably 100 different ways this could be done.  Until you know the method they are using, you won't know how to modify it (if at all).  For instance, it could be done at the firewall level, or it could be done at the socket level or it could be done with custom transports or any number of ways...

Comment: I know they put the allowed ips in the iis ip restrictions settings.